# How to use multi-core for the MPC5748G?

Tags: algorithm, multicore, lzma, nxp-microcontroller

I'm trying to implement the LZMA algorithm (compression/decompression algorithm) in the MPC5748G, however i need an example on how to use more than one core since there are 2 cores of 160Mhz

I'm using LZMA to reduce flashing time, the file firstly is compressed and then sent to the MPC ... it should then decompress the file and perform the flashing operation.

The algorithm need to run on a separate core because the other core are doing other things and contains a lot of tasks.The results are not very good and the decompression takes too much time.

as @marcus commented: the problem is not to write an lzma decoder, but to run it on a different core

Any help for using the other core will be very helpful.

Comment: so wait, your problem is not to write an lzma decoder, but to run it on a different core?

Comment: yes exactly i added your expression to the question

Answer (score 0):

How about Core_Boot(void)?

```
/*******************************************************************************
Function Name : Core_Boot
Engineer      : Lukas Zadrapa
Date          : Apr-20-2016
Parameters    : NONE
Modifies      : NONE
Returns       : NONE
Notes         : Start e200z4b and e200z2 cores
Issues        : NONE
*******************************************************************************/
void Core_Boot(void)
{
    /* Enable e200z4b and e200z2 cores in RUN0-RUN3, DRUN and SAFE modes */
    MC_ME.CCTL[2].R = 0x00FC;   /* e200z4b is active */
    MC_ME.CCTL[3].R = 0x00FC;   /* e200z2 is active */

    /* Set start address for e200z4b and e200z2 cores */    
    MC_ME.CADDR[2].R = E200Z4B_BOOT_ADDRESS | 1; /* e200z4b boot address + RMC bit */
    MC_ME.CADDR[3].R = E200Z2_BOOT_ADDRESS | 1; /* e200z2 boot address + RMC bit */ 

    /* Mode change - re-enter the DRUN mode to start cores */
    MC_ME.MCTL.R = 0x30005AF0;      /* Mode & Key */
    MC_ME.MCTL.R = 0x3000A50F;      /* Mode & Key inverted */

    while(MC_ME.GS.B.S_MTRANS == 1);    /* Wait for mode entry complete */
    while(MC_ME.GS.B.S_CURRENT_MODE != 0x3);    /* Check DRUN mode entered */
}//Core_Boot
```

Do you need to exchange data between cores? Regards